# Get object inside object in view in laravel

Tags: php, date, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have an object in my laravel view that should have an object inside an object but I can't access the child object with object notation. I can access the child properties in array notation.

In my view I can access the parent attributes with:

`$model->Model`

but this won't work to access the child attributes in [specs]:

`$model->specs->updated_at`

This works

`$model['specs']['updated_at']`

I am trying to get the updated_at value in the specs child, but the value that gets returned with `$model['specs']['updated_at']` is not correct. The value in the object is "0000-00-00 00:00:00", but the value returned with `$model['specs']['updated_at']` is "-0001-11-30 00:00:00". This is why I'm trying to use object notation to see if that returns the correct value.

Here is the print_r on the object:

```
Pricing Object
(
    [primaryKey:protected] => ModelID
    [table:protected] => Pricing
    [connection:protected] => design
    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [incrementing] => 1
    [timestamps] => 1
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [ModelID] => 2762
            [MakeID] => 151
            [Model] => 240MK
            [Cost] => 17076
            [MarkUp] => 0.134690
            [OptionID] => A
            [Surcharge] => 0.00
            [MAP] => 21999
            [galleryId] => 1158
            [Base] => 18300
            [Discount] => 3000
            [Mandatory_Options] => 3500, 150, 30, 96
            [Option_Discount] => 2000
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2014-02-17 14:22:18
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [ModelID] => 2762
            [MakeID] => 151
            [Model] => 240MK
            [Cost] => 17076
            [MarkUp] => 0.134690
            [OptionID] => A
            [Surcharge] => 0.00
            [MAP] => 21999
            [galleryId] => 1158
            [Base] => 18300
            [Discount] => 3000
            [Mandatory_Options] => 3500, 150, 30, 96
            [Option_Discount] => 2000
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2014-02-17 14:22:18
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [specs] => Spec Object
                (
                    [primaryKey:protected] => ModelID
                    [table:protected] => Specs
                    [connection:protected] => design
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [ModelID] => 2762
                            [Dry] => 5292
                            [GVWR] => 0
                            [Cargo] => 1908
                            [Tongue] => 0
                            [Axle] => 0
                            [Height] => 131
                            [Length] => 331
                            [Width] => 0
                            [Interior] => 0
                            [Fresh] => 43
                            [Gray] => 60
                            [Black] => 30
                            [Awning] => 0
                            [Type] => A
                            [Bunks] => H
                            [Fiberglass] => I
                            [Slideout] => 1
                            [Updatestamp] => 012513
                            [Sleeps] => 3
                            [Vents] => 0
                            [Exterior_Kitchen] => L
                            [Exterior_Doors] => 1
                            [Awning_Size1] => 
                            [Awning_Size2] => 
                            [Awning_Size3] => 
                            [Awning_Size4] => 
                            [Awning_Size5] => 
                            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [ModelID] => 2762
                            [Dry] => 5292
                            [GVWR] => 0
                            [Cargo] => 1908
                            [Tongue] => 0
                            [Axle] => 0
                            [Height] => 131
                            [Length] => 331
                            [Width] => 0
                            [Interior] => 0
                            [Fresh] => 43
                            [Gray] => 60
                            [Black] => 30
                            [Awning] => 0
                            [Type] => A
                            [Bunks] => H
                            [Fiberglass] => I
                            [Slideout] => 1
                            [Updatestamp] => 012513
                            [Sleeps] => 3
                            [Vents] => 0
                            [Exterior_Kitchen] => L
                            [Exterior_Doors] => 1
                            [Awning_Size1] => 
                            [Awning_Size2] => 
                            [Awning_Size3] => 
                            [Awning_Size4] => 
                            [Awning_Size5] => 
                            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [exists] => 1
                    [softDelete:protected] => 
                )

        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [exists] => 1
    [softDelete:protected] => 
)
```

Comment: Try to check the object using `dd($model->specs)`, you can see all the properties.

Comment: I can see the properties of specs with `dd($model->specs)` but I still cannot access its attributes with `$model->specs->ModelID`

Comment: Post your relationship methods and post what you get when you do `dd($model->specs)`.

Comment: I ended up just using this `$model['specs']['updated_at']` because I had to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class one
{

    public $hello="hello";
}
class two
{

    public $welcome;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->welcome  = new one();
    }
}
$two=new two();
$two->welcome->hello;
?>
```